# Stanford POS tagger in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use POS tagger in Maven project.

```
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("models\\english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
String str = readFile();
String tagged = tagger.tagString(str);
System.out.println(tagged);
```

I got this error info.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<clinit>(MaxentTagger.java:224)
```

The version of POS tagger is 3.7.0, and using eclipse.

I tried to edit the pom.xml, but the version is really old and can't work...

Comment: There are instructions here for using Stanford CoreNLP with Maven: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Comment: You will need to use this path to access the pos model: edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger , which is the path of the resource in the distributed resources jar

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp Thank you for your response!!